# my test class showing 0% code coverage

Tags: trigger

I have to make trigger on opportunity whenever new opp is created create a post on account.

my trigger

```
trigger postOnAcc on Opportunity (after insert) {
     List<FeedItem> posts = new List<FeedItem>();  //create a list to hold post
     List<Id> oppList=new List<Id>();              //create a list to hold new opportunity
    for(Opportunity o:Trigger.new)                  //Iterate for loop on new opportunity
    {
        oppList.add(o.AccountId);                     //add opportunity account id in opportunity list
    }
 for(Opportunity opp: [Select id,name ,AccountId from Opportunity where AccountId in:oppList]) //
 {

    if(opp.AccountId != null){

        FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
        Post.ParentId = opp.AccountId;
        post.body = 'New Opportunity is created with Opportunity Id - '+opp.Id + ' and Opportunity name is equal to - '+opp.Name;
        posts.add(post);  //add this post in posts List

    }
 }
 insert posts;
}
```

my test class

```
@istest
private class testclass {
static testmethod void testclass()
{
    Account a=new Account();
    a.Name='AK';
    insert a; 

    Opportunity o=new opportunity();
    o.Name='AJ';
    o.AccountId=a.Id;
    insert o;

    FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
    Post.ParentId = o.AccountId;
    post.body = 'New Opportunity is created with Opportunity Id - '+o.Id + ' and Opportunity name is equal to - '+o.Name;
    insert post;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of a unit test is not to repeat the code in your main code, but instead to verify that the behavior occurred correctly. Further, I presume your test failed, because the Opportunity insert should fail. There are required fields you must use to insert an Opportunity successfully. Here's a modified test method:

```
@istest class testclass {
    @isTest static void testclass() {
        Account a=new Account();
        a.Name='AK';
        insert a; 

        // Must provide all required fields
        Opportunity o=new opportunity();
        o.Name='AJ';
        o.AccountId=a.Id;
        o.CloseDate=Date.today();
        // Change the following line to a valid Stage Name
        o.StageName='Prospecting';
        insert o;

        // Important: always verify the logic works
        FeedItem post = [SELECT Body FROM FeedItem WHERE ParentId = :a.Id];
        System.assert(post.Body.contains('New Opportunity is created'));

    }
}
```